# @PostConstruct method is being called without the dependency being ready

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
package com.coaches.demoCoaches;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class footballCoach implements coach{
    outfit coachOutfit;
    @Override
    public String getDailyWorkout() {
        return "score 10 goals";
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void coachIsReady(){
        System.out.println("Coach is now ready");
        System.out.println(coachOutfit);
    }
    public outfit getCoachOutfit() {
        return coachOutfit;
    }
    public void setCoachOutfit(outfit coachOutfit) {
        this.coachOutfit = coachOutfit;
    }


}
```

Here is the class i'm creating the PostConstruct method for

```
2023-11-01T00:30:25.910+02:00  INFO 7902 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
2023-11-01T00:30:25.936+02:00  INFO 7902 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-11-01T00:30:25.937+02:00  INFO 7902 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 756 ms
Coach is now ready
null
2023-11-01T00:30:26.134+02:00  INFO 7902 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-11-01T00:30:26.154+02:00  INFO 7902 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-11-01T00:30:26.160+02:00  INFO 7902 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.demoCoaches.DemoCoachesApplication   : Started DemoCoachesApplication in 1.266 seconds (process running for 1.612)
```

and here is the output as you can see the postConstruct method is called and printing the dependency as Null already

I wanted to make sure that the function until I pass the outfit instance to the coach

```
    package com.coaches.demoCoaches;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoCoachesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext myContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoCoachesApplication.class, args);

        footballCoach mycoach =  myContext.getBean(footballCoach.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you include the code where the coach object is being instantiated?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added main function to the post

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: I do not understand. Field `coachOutfit` is never set. How should it be anything different than `null`? Where is theh `coachOutfit` suppose to come from? Is the `outfit`-class annotated with a bean-defining scope-annotation? --- The class `footballCoach` is missing a means to inject the `outfit` in it (preferrably through c'tor injection). --- As an aside: In java, classes should start with an uppercase letter. If you are new to java, maybe don't start with a framework like spring-boot.

Comment: @Turing85 I know coachOutfit is null I'm not asking for a value but I thought the PostConstruct function won't run until I call the setter for coachOutfit and initiate the coachOutfit. isn't that when PostConstruct is suppose to run ?

Comment: [From `@PostConstruct`'s documentation (`jakarta.ee`)](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/annotation/postconstruct): "*The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed **after dependency injection is done** to perform any initialization. ...*" (emphasis is my own)

Comment: @OmarAlsawaf PostConstruct will always run immediately after injection.  In your case, there is nothing to inject, but the injection still completed, which is when your PostConstruct method was invoked.

Comment: @lane.maxwell i didn't inject the outfit on purpose from what i understood the method will only run after i inject the outfit using setter injection but it already ran before doing that this is what is confusing me i thought it will not run until i call the setter injection in main method only after that it will run , what am i not understanding correctly here ?

Comment: I think the part that you're missing is that you do not control the bean construction and initialization, spring does.  Spring is going to invoke the post construct method after spring has constructed the instance and initialized the properties.  This will occur even if there are no properties to set or beans to inject, from spring's perspective, it has completed initialization